# I cannot update my sytem

Tags: 13.10, updates

ubuntu is not getting updated when i try to update it shows:

```
E:Malformed line 43 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
```

My update manager is also not working
when i try to open it from terminal it also show some errors similar to this

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the content of /etc/apt/sources.list